# Problem with changing language in android

Tags: java, android, multilingual

I am working on an android app with multi languages. I have a static method in MainActivity:

```
public static void setLocale(Activity activity, String languageCode) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = activity.getResources();
        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
        config.setLocale(locale);
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

then I changed locale in all activities `onCreate` method (before `setContentView`):

```
MainActivity.setLocale(HomeActivity.this, "fa");
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

It works fine, but when another activity starts and finishes the locale will be back to English (also it doesn't work in SDK 23 or less at all). I want a correct way to change the locale of the app. Sorry if my English is bad

Answer (score 0):

You must override **attachBaseContext**.

I've built this object to set locale.

```
object LocaleHelper {

    fun setLocale(context: Context, language: String): Context {
        val currentLocale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(currentLocale)
        val resources: Resources = context.resources
        val configuration = Configuration(resources.configuration)
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(currentLocale)

        return when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
                val localeList = LocaleList(currentLocale)
                val config = Configuration().apply {
                    setLocale(currentLocale)
                    setLocales(localeList)
                }
                context.createConfigurationContext(config)
            }
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 -> {
                val config = Configuration().apply {
                    setLocale(currentLocale)
                }
                context.createConfigurationContext(config)
            }
            else -> {
                val config = Configuration().apply {
                    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                    locale = currentLocale
                }
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                context.resources.updateConfiguration(
                        config,
                        context.resources.displayMetrics
                )
                context
            }
        }
    }

    fun onAttach(context: Context, localeName: String): Context {
        return setLocale(context, localeName)
    }
}
```

In your activity do this:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(context: Context?) {
    if(context != null)
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(context, "fa"))
    else
        super.attachBaseContext(context)
}
```